# LinkedLIst Object is not considered of the same type as ListNode even though it has the same properties

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am solving the Merge Two Sorted List problem on leetcode. I put the values from the two list into an array, and I sorted the array. The problem comes in when I am trying to convert the array back into a linked list. I am attempting to recreate the linkedlist object based on the definition they gave me.

```
function ListNode(val, next) {
      this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
      this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
}
```

I used  `new ListNode(val,next)` to turn the array back into a linked list
Here is the code for that:

```
head = new Object() //the value of head gets changed to a ListNode on the first index
for(let i = saved.length-1; i > -1 ;i--){
        if(i ==saved.length-1){
           head = new ListNode(saved[i],null);
        }
        else{
           head = new ListNode(saved[i],head);
        }
    }
    console.log(head);
    return head;
```

head appears as [1,1,2,3,4,4]
and `typeof head` logs Object.

This error is thrown:

```
throw new TypeError(__serialize__(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type ListNode");
```

From what I can tell, the return value of head should be a ListNode as it uses the ListNode constructor and it has the same next and val properties.
How can I have my output recognized as a ListNode object?

Things I have tried

-Using there ListNode constructor
-Creating an Object and adding the properties val and next.
-branching the last node of the first ListNode with the first node of the second ListNode and overwriting the values. ie: head = startingnode; head.val = saved[i]; head = head.next;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will occur when `saved` is an empty array. I checked the LeetCode problem constraints, and the input could indeed be two empty lists, i.e. your array would be empty.

In that case, your function returns `new Object()`, which is not an expected value. In this case the function should return `null`, which is what represents an empty linked list.

So don't create that `new Object()`, but just initialise `head` as `null`. This brings a second advantage: you don't need the `if..else` anymore. Finally, make sure to define `head` as a local variable (with `let`):

```
function makeList(saved) {
    let head = null;
    for (const value of saved.reverse()){
        head = new ListNode(value, head);
    }
    saved.reverse() // Optionally restore the original order in the array
    return head;
}
```

#### Remark

There is another challenge here: try to solve it without allocating memory for copying the values (like your array), and without creating new `ListNode` instances. These code challenges are intended to be solved by rewiring the *existing* node instances.